# fgets implementation (K&R)

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to programming, starting off with Objective-C but have decided to go back to basics before progressing further. I'm spending some time on C, and am struggling through pointer confusion. My question is about how K&R says fgets is implemented (p165, 2nd ed.) Code below is direct from the text with a couple of my comments.

```
char* fgets(char* s, int n, FILE *iop)
{
    register int c;
    register char* cs;
    cs = s;

    while(--n > 0 && (c = getc(iop)) != EOF)
    {
    // put the input char into the current pointer position, then increment it
    // if a newline entered, break
    if((*cs++ = c) == '\n')
        break;          
    }

    *cs = '\0';
    return (c == EOF && cs == s) ? NULL : s;
}
```

1) We pass a char* s to the fgets function, at whose location we store the user input. Why is there a need to declare the local char* cs - and then initialise it to s? Why can't we directly manipulate/add to s within the if statement? Seeing as cs is initialised to point s, isn't adding the chars to cs exactly the same thing?

2) Tied in with the above...When the function returns, a test is made to see if cs == s. Why is this necessary?

I think I may be missing something very fundamental - I did check SO and Google but can't quite figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: "starting off with Objective-C but have decided to go back to basics before progressing further" - excellent, **every beginner should do that.**

Comment: I was just beginning to feel like I was hitting a stride of sorts in Obj-C. Since going back to C I feel like a complete klutz again, but despite repeatedly banging my head against segmentation faults and odd program behaviour, it is definitely worth the effort.

Comment: It is most certainly worth it. Mastering C is inevitable for understanding Objective-C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the check on the last line, `cs == s`. This comparison checks the modified pointer `cs` against the original `s` to see if we've read any character. If we haven't then we return NULL.

By using `cs` throughout the original pointer `s` is preserved. If `s` were directly manipulated (`*s++` instead of `*cs++`) then we'd have to find another way to check whether any characters were read.

One can also argue that it's a good practice to leave function parameters alone and treat them as `const`. Some programmers follow this practice as a way to enhance code clarity.

Comment: Thanks very much John. That makes the intention clearer, but a couple more questions if I may...when 'cs' is assigned with 'cs = s', I figured that the pointers were now pointing to exactly the same area of memory; therefore that performing '*cs++' would be exactly equivalent to '*s++'. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: Sorry my comment timed out, and am doing comment markup wrong as well.... It is why I didn't understand the final line. I thought that seeing as both pointers were "sharing", then they would be identical when the c==cs expression evaluated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GasMan14 They are pointing to the same address after the assignment, that's correct. `*cs++` doesn't modify `s`, though. Make sure you understand the precedence: `*cs++` is equal to `*(cs++)` not `(*cs)++`. `cs++` increments `cs`, making it point to the next address, then the `*` dereferences that address. `s` is not changed because `s` and `cs` are two separate variables. If the statement were `(*cs)++` instead then that *would* change the value of `*s`. (Mind you, not `s`, but `*s`.)

Comment: @JohnKugelman Why did they use `register int c; register char* cs;`? Why not `int c`, and `char* cs`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman just to understand: why if `if((*cs++ = c) == '\n')` is true, before the `break` we dont decrement the `cs` (`cs--`) ? If we do this, when the program go out from the while, can override the `\n`. Why we prefer don't do this and return the `\n` ?

Comment: @Kyrol It's annoying, but that's the way `fgets()` is specified to work. ["Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case `str` will contain that newline character."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: @JohnKugelman but `The produced character string is always null-terminated` is not always true. Actually , for example, if we're reading only the `\n`, and we have a buffer with len = 1, or we put *1* as 2nd par of the `fgets`, we override the `\n` with `\0`.
Ok maybe is a borderline case, but exists. So I don't understand why nobody wanna universally change the implementation of a function if is well known its behaviour. I know my question is kinda "philosophic" and ambitious. Thanks you for your time. :)

Comment: If `n` is 1 then no input is read and `fgets` sets the first character to `'\0'` and immediately returns. The string is always null-terminated. The newline is left at the end only if there is room for it; otherwise the newline is left unread to be picked up by the next I/O call. `fgets` can't be changed because it's a part of the standard C library. It's too late to change its behavior. Millions of programs expect it to behave this way.

Comment: @JohnKugelman "`cs++` increments `cs`, making it point to the next address, then the `*` dereferences that address." That's incorrect. Isn't it? `cs++` yields `cs`. `*` dereferences that yielded `cs`. `cs++` increments `cs` *after* yielding the `cs` so `*` *does not* dereference the incremented new value but older yielded value.

Comment: @rootkea Yes, you're right. I don't know why I worded it that way. I should have said `*` dereferences *the previous address*.