# I'm having a hard time understanding the fgets() function

Tags: c, pointers, fgets

I'm preparing for an exam next week and I'm having a hard time understanding the `fgets()` function in C.

Given this example:

```
void main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[2]
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)
    /*I understand that this loop returns true aslong 
    as End-of-File is not encountered*/

    printf("%s", buff);

    fclose(fp)
}
```

As far as I understand this loop will get a char array of 2 elements (1 character + `'\0'`), how does it know to skip already gotten elements? does it have something to do with the `fp` pointer?

Comment: Your string is going to be empty every time since fgets reads the carriage return and places a null terminator. That's two bytes.

Comment: `fgets` comes from `file-get-string`. You try to read a string not a char array of 2 elements. Read https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/.

Comment: @Akali You are wrong. Exactly one character is read. The new line character is not appended.

Comment: @Tudor He reads a string of length 1.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You're right . For a moment I thought he was reading from terminal.

Comment: The `FILE *fp` handle keeps track of a lot of internal variables, like the position in the file and a lot more.

Comment: The short answer is that “something” keeps track of the position for the file handle that you have open (here abstracted into the `FILE` pointed to by `fp`). What and how depends on how the underlying file is implemented.

Comment: @Cheatah The position is not _necessarily_ tracked in the internal variables of the `FILE`. Consider reading directly from a file descriptor, which is just an `int`, yet those too maintain the position. The position may be tracked by the OS, for example.

Comment: Thanks all! That was some useful clarification.

Answer (score 0):

FILE is an object type used for streams and an abstraction that implements a buffer along with a pointer into that buffer.  [`fgets()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) copes data from the stream into the array you supply to `gets()` and advances the pointer.

This example [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397832/fgets-implementation-kr) might be instructive.

In glibc, `fgets()` is a macro for [`__fgets_unlocked()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/libio/iofgets_u.c#L66) and eventually ends up calling [`_IO_getline_info()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/libio/iogetline.c#L34).